Disabling microphone when secondary one is connected
I'd like to add a 3.5 mm female jack to this circuit so that I can add a better external microphone while keeping the internal one for convenience. What would the circuit look like?
Putting both microphones in parallel doesn't seem like a good idea, so I'd want the first microphone to be disconnected when the jack is inserted (so when one circuit is closed the other opens.) Would adding a simple transistor like in the second picture work or would it cause issues?
If you have any idea of how to implement it properly it would be very appreciated.
While a jack with integrated swich would be the simplest solution I was hoping for something else. I'm planning to put this circuit into a Razer Electra, and using the jack for microphone that it already has would be a lot less of a hassle.
Unfortunatly I can't find the schematics of the board nor the chip itself. (I know it's not of much help, but I uploaded a couple more pictures.)
Circuit



Diagram now/with jack


Use a jack that contains a switch, and have the switch disconnect the internal microphone.

Your transistor circuit drawing should be red "I have an idea of inserting a transistor and maybe also some other parts to do the switching. Thus I have already invented the essence of the solution - that's a transistor and maybe also other parts connected. Now I need only someone to do the non-creative part of the design job!"
Unfortunately we know nothing what's the type of your original mic and which kind mic you are going to insert to the jack. Most of us probably would guess you have an electret capsule on the board. If that guess happens to be right it should be possible to use a jack which has switches and inserting to the jack an external electret capsule would replace the original one.
Making another mic type to work needs much more complex, but still successful guesses. Or some reverse engineering of your board. Something like Shure SM58 placed with jack switches in the place of the original can work, but more likely it doesn't because electret capsules have a DC circuit and the available audio AC voltages are also different.
Placing another electret capsule in parallel with the original has chances to be successful. But you very likely must somehow shut mechanically the hole of the original mic to stop it catching noises.
As said above, electret capsules make a DC path. You could feed the DC of your original mic through a mosfet or bipolar transistor, say through part X in the new circuit. The external electret mic uses also some DC. That current could be used to turn off X. The construction probably is simple if you allow 2 transistors, but it's impossible to draw it right nor calculate the needed resistors without having your board in one's hands for reverse engineering the mic input circuit.
A proper schematic of your board would reduce radically the need of guessing. I'm afraid the moderator closes your question if you do not soon provide any information of the actual circuits on your board.

ok, thank you for the info, tried connecting the mic in parallel and it does work i guess i could either have a switch or try to use the jack hole as mic hole so it gets shut mechanically as you suggested, i also updated the question to give a bit more details
